# Very simple lookup of a Plist in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, plist

I want to do a very simple task with a Plist, but I'm very new to all this. I have a variable integer, x , in the app and want to look up the integer in the first array of the PList and return a corresponding string from the second array. The filename of the plist is AApropertylist.plist and its XML version is thus:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>number</key>
<array>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <integer>2</integer>
    <integer>3</integer>
</array>
<key>textreturn</key>
<array>
    <string>Text of 1</string>
    <string>Text of 2</string>
    <string>Text of 3</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

(this is a very truncated version, both arrays go up to 45000)

The "Text of 1" "Text of 2" is just placeholder text, the real data is still being compiled. The goal is the app will display the text result on a label

I would really appreciate some help, I've looked everywhere but I suspect the solution is so simple noone has bothered to write a tutorial, I can only find stuff pertaining to more complex Plist structures and table views etc.

thanks in anticipation!

-Tim

Comment: If your integers are unique, you'd better use a simple dictionary, eg: `1->"text of 1", 4->"text of 4", 77->"text of 77"`. The lookups will be much faster.

Comment: That does look a lot simpler, but how do I set up such a plist in plist view? should the root be a dictionary and each new item be a dictionary? And how do I do the lookups?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a dictionary with the numbers as the key, it would save you having to load two relatively large arrays. You could do it something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>1</key>
<string>String 1</string>
<key>2</key>
<string>String 2</string>
<key>3</key>
<string>String 3</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then to load it nice and simply:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AApropertylist" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSString *returnedString = [dict objectForKey:@"ANY_NUMBER"];
```

Comment: Thanks, that does look like a much better way of writing the plist.

Comment: However I'm still completely lost as to how I lookup the value x from the key and return the string. When I tried this code there was a warning on the second line "Use of undeclared identifier "file"", i assume it's meant to read "path" rather than "file" to refer to the string created in the line above..? In the third line I think the *returnedString is meant to be the result of the lookup, but I have no idea whatsoever what "ANY_NUMBER" is. Assuming it's meant to be the number to look up from the key in the plist, i replaced "ANY_NUMBER" with the string"2" hoping..

Comment: ..it would return *returnedString as "String 2" from the plist, but it's null

Comment: Ah my mistake, if you replace 'file' in 'initWithContentsOfFile' to 'path'. It wasn't initializing with the your plist - I updated it in my answer

Comment: Thankyou so much.. I was making a mistake too, i read the wrong plist file name from the file structure. With those changes, it's working perfectly. I really appreciate all your help

Answer (score 0):

```
NSObject myPlistContent = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filename];
```

But double check whether it is really an NSDictionary that your receive. I think the root object would always be a dict but I do not sign that in blood. 
The Dictionary may contain further Dictionaries, Arrays, Strings, Dates, Data and Numbers which depend on the contents and structure of the plist.

Answer (score 0):

You should load the plist and have it as an NSDictionary (or array)
here is a quick code to get you in the right direction

```
// path = the path which your plist file is located
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"plist"];


// Break the plist file into an array so we can play with the data
NSArray* a = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path]; 
// now you have the plist as an array (it is called a)

// next line is a loop which runs on our array (a) and each element is becoming an NSDictionary called d



for (NSDictionary *d in a)
{

    // just take the value for a single element (d) with the value "number"
    // store it in a string called cdata
    NSString *cdate = [d objectForKey:@"number"];
   // if this value is equal to "something" do your thing
    if ([cdate isEqualToString:@"SOMTHING"])
    {

        // do something with text here
    }
}
```

Comment: I kind of understand the first bit, but then I get lost. Unfortunately, you're dealing with someone who's extremely new to this. Is *cdate meant to be the result for the label? Does this code come after the loading of the plist as an NSDictionary as you mention (because I don't know how to do that). Does "number" refer to the "number" array in my code? and what is the string "SOMTHING" and also, where is the reference to the text array "textreturn". sorry if these questions seem stupid..

Comment: Look at my answer again, I added comments for you to understand this better - its much simpler than you think ;)

Comment: That does help me get a bit closer to understanding it, "something" is my integer x, yes? , but where do I retrieve the texreturn array result? I can't see reference to it here. Just to be clear I want to compare integer x with integers from array "number" and return text from array"textreturn". I don't know what corresponds with what in your example, but it feels tsntalizingly close!

Comment: try to read and understand the following link talking about Key - Value coding - http://www.andyibanez.com/key-value-coding-key-value-observing-cocoa-bindings-basic-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the link but it's pretty much completely beyond me unfortunately